# ActiveRecord sum per uniq attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Active Record of invoices with the attributes `:quarter` and `:revenue`.
Examples for quarter are "Q1 2015", "Q2 2015", "Q4 2014", etc..

What I want to do is make a map with each `:quarter` and the sum of `:revenue` for each unique quarter.

I know how to get a map with each unique `:quarter`

```
@bills.map {|bill| bill.quarter}.uniq
```

and I know how to make a map that sums the `:revenue`

```
@bills.map {|bill| bill.revenue}.sum
```

How can I combine those two?

Comment: So you're trying to calculate how much you earned per quarter?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do, yes! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a ActiveRecord query directly.

```
@bills.group(:quarter).sum(:revenue)
```

Comment: I noticed that `@bills` is not an ActiveRecord. Actually I get it from a JSON and the model is a non-ActiveRecord one. So `@bills` is an object array. How could I get the same result with this?

Comment: You can use the Enumerable method: `#group_by` as well as `#transform_values` and `#sum` which is added to the Hash and Enumerable classes by Rails respectively:

`@bills.group_by(&:quarter).transform_values { |v| v.sum(&:revenue) }`